# Does Airforce one carry missiles to protect itself and its passengers?

Tags: military, missiles, head-of-state-transport, air-force-one

Do the VC-25 aircraft used for [Air Force One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_One) carry missiles to protect itself and its passengers?

If so, can these missiles be fired at potential threats?

Comment: I edited it to specify the aircraft used rather than the call sign. I believe that’s what the OP intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near as is know outside of a security clearance the answer is no, a Boeing VC-25 does not carry missiles or offensive weaponry.  During times of crisis, VC-25s are often escorted by armed jet fighters which can attack potential threats to the VC-25 if need be.

Answer (score 2):

Following [this source](http://www.fi-aeroweb.com/Defense/VC-25-Air-Force-One.html), the armament is "none".

An aircraft so big looks more like like a bomber, and large bombers in these days tend to rely on the escorting fighter aircraft to defend them. On board self-defence weapons of the bomber are not efficient, see [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/49651/how-effective-was-wwii-bombers-self-defense-anti-air-armament/49667#49667). I think VC-25 just does the same.

Other large aircraft with the potential management role, like [Boeing E-3 Sentry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_E-3_Sentry), [Lockheed EC-121 Warning Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_EC-121_Warning_Star) or [Boeing E-767](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_E-767) also appear unarmed even if they are much more battle oriented.