# How effective was the computer-controlled gunnery on the B29?

Tags: military, wwii, b-29

The Boeing B29 Superfortress was equipped with multiple gun turrets which were linked to a [central
computerised fire control system.](https://airandspace.si.edu/stories/editorial/defending-superbomber-b-29s-central-fire-control-system) This [training film](https://youtu.be/mJExsIp4yO8) covers the gunner's control interface, which looks astonishingly advanced for the 1940's.

How effective was this gunnery arrangement?
Are there published statistics showing how its defences compared to other bombers of the time?

[Related question.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/49651/how-effective-was-wwii-bombers-self-defense-anti-air-armament)

Comment: That's more a question about gunnery than aircraft, especially when asking for statistics on gun effectivity.

Comment: The system was really the original true "fly by wire" control system, just not a flight control.  The gunner's sight head used Selsyn synchros to send voltages to the computer representing azimuth, elevation and range, and the computer sent modified voltages to Selsyns in the turret(s), and where the guns were pointed was not where the sight head pointed, but where the computer decided they should be pointed after applying all the correction schedules. So the gun barrels were never actually parallel to the sight head axis, but pointing somewhere else as the computer saw fit.